# Error when installing gimp from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-installation, gimp

Last night my internet connection was slow so I canceled Gimp installation (4.5 Mb/53Mb). But today when I try to click on Gimp install button in Ubuntu Software Center, this error came up "Requires installation of untrusted packages". What should I do now?

Comment: nope.sudo apt -get update solved my problem.

Comment: What do you think the first answer of that question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close software-center and then open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, open software and try the install again and you should not see the same error.